# Append timestamp to SSRS-2008 report when exported?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In an SSRS-2008 report, is it possible to automatically alter the name of the file when the report is exported?  Specifically, is it possible to append the current date and time to the file name?

For exapmle, a report named "Order Summary" could be automatically named Order_Summary_2013_10_10.xls when the export link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using report viewer control in your application to display reports you can try this: http://www.jimandkatrin.com/CodeBlog/post/Setting-export-file-name-in-SSRS-report-viewer.aspx

If you are using ssrs as standalone application you will not be able to do this.